# Finding the x's for which f(x) is a whole number

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to improve my math skills and I found this exercise in my book.

We have the following function: $$f: \mathbb R\to \mathbb R$$  $$f(x) = \frac {4x+1}3$$ I've been asked to find out one value for $x$ such that $f(x)$ is a whole number. I found some solutions and afterwards I determined that for all $$x_n=\frac {3^{2n}-1}4$$  where n is a natural number different from 0 , $f(x_n)$ is a whole number. I'm not 100% sure this is correct but it seems to work for all positive even powers of 3.

I've been trying to prove that this formula is corect, but I didn't succeed. Could anyone point me out on how to prove this kind of problems, and what to watch out for? Thanks.

Comment: This is hard to read.  Do you mean $\frac {3^{2n}-1}4$?

Comment: yes, that's what I was trying to display

Comment: Of course, that expression only covers a small subset of the possible cases.  For instance $x=2$ works.  Indeed, any number of the form $x=2+3k$ for $k\in \mathbb Z$ works.

Comment: To prove it works just not $f(\frac {3^{2n} -1}4) = \frac {4(\frac {3^{2n} -1}4) +1}3 = \frac {(3^{2n} -1) + 1}3 = \frac {3^{2n}}3 = 3^{2n-1}$.  Which is a whole number so long as $n \ge 1$.  !!But!!! It's important to realize those aren't the *only* answers.  Try to figure out which $x$ will give you $f(x) = m$.  That is $\frac {4x + 1}3 = m$.

Answer (score 2):

To see that your expression always works, note that $$3^{2n}=(3^2)^n=9^n=(1+8)^n=1+n\times 8 + \binom n2\times 8^2 +\cdots + 8^n\implies$$$$3^{2n}-1= n\times 8 + \binom n2\times 8^2 +\cdots + 8^n$$ which is manifestly divisible by $4$, and even divisible by $8$.

More broadly, though any integer of the form $x=3k+2$ (for integer $k$) will work.

Answer (score 1):

$$ (4x+1)/3 = k $$

$$ (4x+1)=3k$$

$$ 4x=3k-1 $$

$$ x=(3k-1)/4$$

Thus for all integers  $ k \ge 0 $ if  you let $x=(3k-1)/4 $, you will get $f(x)=k$ which is a whole number.

Answer (score 0):

For $\frac {4x + 1}3= m \in \mathbb N$

Then $4x + 1 = 3m$

$4x = 3m -1$

$x = \frac {3m -1}4$.  Now $x$ doesn't have to be a whole number so for $m = 0,1,2,3,4,5.....$ we get $x = \frac {-1}{4}, \frac {1}{2}, 2, \frac {11}4, \frac 72....$  and $f(x) = 0,1,2,3,4,5..... $ etc.

Now if $m = 3^{2n-1}$ then $x = \frac {3*3^{2n-1} -1}4 = \frac {3^{2n} -1}4$ is certainly acceptable but *very* *very* specific.

====

In other words:

$\frac{4(\frac {3^{2n} - 1}4) + 1}{3}=\frac {(3^{2n}- 1) + 1}3=\frac {3^{2n}}3 = 3^{2n-1}$ is certainly a whole number.

But so is $\frac {4(\frac {3m-1}4) + 1}3 = \frac {(3m-1)+1}3 = \frac {3m}3 = m$.

Answer (score 0):

You have found some of the solutions... you have not found all of the solutions.

If $f(n)$ is a solution
$f(n +3) = \frac {4(n+3) + 1}{3} = \frac {4n + 1}{3} + 4$

And so once you find one, then you know that adding $3$ will give another.

So will subtracting $3.$

Another way to think about it...

$f(x) = \frac {4x + 1}{3}\\
f(x) = \frac {3x+x + 1}{3}\\
f(x) = x + \frac {x + 1}{3}$

And so then you need to find those $x$ such that the last term is an integer.